# I want replace substring in string

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, substring, dos

```
01: SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
02: ... 
03:  IF /i "%tValueType%" EQU "string" (
04:   SET "vValueBefore=%1"
05:   SET "vValueAfter=%2"
06: 
07:   FOR %%p IN (equ neq sub) DO (
08:    IF /i "!tOperator!" EQU "%%p" (
09:     SET "tOperatorValid=valid"
10:     IF /i "!tOperator!" EQU "sub" (
11:      SET "tConditions="!vValueAfter:!vValueBefore!=!" NEQ "!vValueAfter!""
12:     ) ELSE (
13:      SET "tConditions="!vValueBefore!" %tOperator% "!vValueAfter!""
14:     )
15:    )
16:   )
17:  )
18: ...
```

Line 11: I want replace substring to "" (cut substring) in string but error.

Comment: Please tag the language you are using. 1) for more exposure. 2) So others know what language you are working with. 3) For some languages you will get syntax highlighting :)

Comment: I use batch script :)

Comment: You can edit your question, and at the bottom, add a tag

Comment: I took care of it.  Carry on...   :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
11:      for /F "delims=" %%v in ("!vValueBefore!") do SET "tConditions="!vValueAfter:%%~v=!" NEQ "!vValueAfter!""
```

Comment: Thank you I code
    FOR /f "delims=" %%v IN ("!vValueBefore!") DO (
     SET "tConditions="!vValueAfter:%%~v=!" NEQ "!vValueAfter!""
    )

Comment: +1, However, if vValueBefore may begin with any character, including `;`, then should disable EOL using `for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%v ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
  SET "tConditions="!vValueAfter:%vValueBefore%=!" NEQ "!vValueAfter!""
```

should work, since vValueBefore is not being changed in the loop

Comment: Line 04: I set vValueBefore in if. I not can get value of %vValueBefore%. If echo %vValueBefore% in line 11 -> "echo is off"